# Ubuntu on Macbook Pro doesn't suspend properly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, laptop, macbook

I have installed Ubuntu 19.10 on my late 2015 Macbook Pro with Retina. When I close the lid, the apple logo turns off indicating that it's gone to sleep , however, after a few seconds the light come back on. This seems to keep happenning where the light goes off but then comes back on.

Anyone know what might be causing this and/or how to fix it. It's killing my battery with the current situtation pretty quickly.

Answer (score 4):

Okay so there isn't a proper fix for this yet and there's an open bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1507472).

I followed the workaround mentioned [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mac#Wake_Up_After_Suspend) and while it's not perfect, it does the job for now.

```
cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
```

Check to see that XHC1 and LID0 are enabled. If they are, disabling them will fix the problem. After disabling them, the only way to wake up your computer from suspend is by using the power button.

To do this type to following command (vim can be any cli editor)

```
sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/suspend-fix.service
```

Then add the following text and save:

```
[Unit]
Description=Fix for the suspend issue
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo XHC1 > /proc/acpi/wakeup && echo LID0 > /proc/acpi/wakeup"
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

And then run the following:

```
systemctl enable suspend-fix.service
systemctl start suspend-fix.service
```

Disabling only XHC1 is not recommended if you have this bug, since it may result in glitchy behavior.